# How to add the YouTube player in my SupportFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, fragment

My XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/Container.MainBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code in Fragment

```
public class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "MyKey";
    static private final String VIDEO = "ToMpzhdUD1Q";
    static private final String VIDEO1 = "K77avo920Jc";
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View videoView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_fragment, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Youtube");

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerSupportFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
        youTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

        return videoView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(VIDEO);
        list.add(VIDEO1);
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
        youTubePlayer.cueVideos(list);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "FAIL!" + youTubeInitializationResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }
}
```

In Main activity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Error when I try to open my Fragment in Drawer:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a()' on a null
>   object reference at
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onStart(Unknown
>   Source)

Comment: Any solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you overwrite the **onCreateView()** method from the super class **YouTubePlayerSupportFragment**, a method which is not abstract, and which actually has an implementation, as seen:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater var1, ViewGroup var2, Bundle var3) {
        this.c = new YouTubePlayerView(this.getActivity(), (AttributeSet)null, 0, this.a);
        this.a();
        return this.c;
    }
```

The actual variable names, and types are beyond the scope of this answer.
What matters here is that **YouTubePlayerView** is getting instantiated here, and you overwrite the method, so **YouTubePlayerView** is null, when called in the **onStart()** method (also found in **YouTubePlayerSupportFragment**).

```
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        this.c.a();
    }
```

Therefore, basically, the only things you need, is to instantiate your **VideoFragment** class, and, if you want the actual video, instead of a black box, you need to initialize the fragment, at the time of its creation, (like this:)

```
    public VideoFragment()
    {
        this.initialize("yourAPIKeyHere", this);
    }
```

Comment: I ran into this issue in Xamarin and your post saved me! I just had to use the `Initialize` method inside the constructor. Also comes with very great explanation thank you!