# Use YoutubePlayerView on fragment section

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

I found some similar situation, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269417/youtube-player-crashes-java-lang-nullpointerexception-null-object-reference) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128042/how-to-add-the-youtube-player-in-my-supportfragment/43287970), but none of then solved my problem.

I have wanna have a screen with youtube video and some text information like this:

[image]

I'm using a **activity** and a **fragment**, both with base class that extended **YouTubeBaseActivity** and **YouTubePlayerFragment**.

But when I'm trying to open the fragment it show a npe but it don't show where. Since I'm getting the layout and view right, I don't now what is going on.

**Hope that it don't get downvotes because is a npe question, but is different from usual, this API call don't show me where the NPE happen and I saw the other people has problems like this**

Obs: I'm using this extend base concept because more places will have this videos behaviour and I'm trying to avoid code repeat.

**Logcat**
[image]

**XML**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".screens.mine.fragments.MineStepsFragment">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/mine_steps_youtube_player"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background_white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
    </com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class MineAccidentActivity extends BaseYoutubeActivity {

@Override
protected void initializeActionBar() {
    actionbarLeftBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    actionbarTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected int getActionbarTitle() {
    return R.string.mine_accident;
}

@Override
protected int getContentView() {
    return R.layout.mine_accident_activity;
}

@Override
protected void assignViews() {
    MineAccidentController.getInstance().attachToActivity(this, R.id.mine_container);
}

@Override
protected void prepareViews() {}

///////////////////  BACK  ////////////////////
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!MineAccidentController.getInstance().isFirstFragmentShown()) {
        MineAccidentController.getInstance().showPreviousFragment();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

///////////////////  LIFE CYCLE  ////////////////////
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    MineAccidentController.getInstance().onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

**Fragment Controller**

```
public class MineAccidentController extends BaseYoutubeController {

private String accidentType;

@Override
protected ArrayList<android.app.Fragment> initFragments() {
    ArrayList<android.app.Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    fragments.add(new MineStepsFragment());
    return fragments;
}

//create Class
public static MineAccidentController getInstance() {
    if (null == instance) {
        synchronized (MineAccidentController.class) {
            if (null == instance) {
                setInstance(new MineAccidentController());
            }
        }
    }
    return (MineAccidentController) instance;
}

public String getAccidentType() {
    return accidentType;
}

public void setAccidentType(String accidentType) {
    this.accidentType = accidentType;
}
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class MineStepsFragment extends BaseYoutubeFragment {

//Not in Layout
private String videoUrl;

////////////// IMPLEMENT_METHODS //////////////
@Override
protected int getFragmentContentView() {
    return R.layout.mine_steps_fragment;
}

@Override
protected int getYoutubePlayerView() {
    return R.id.mine_steps_youtube_player;
}

@Override
protected void assignViews() {

}

@Override
protected void prepareViews() {

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

    if(!wasRestored){
        checkType();
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoUrl);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    showErrorToast(getActivity(), R.string.error_initialize_video);
}

////////////// FUNCTIONS //////////////
private void checkType() {
    if(MineAccidentController.getInstance().getAccidentType().equals(Parameters.ACCIDENT_PERSONAL)){
        videoUrl = Properties.MINE_PERSONAL_VIDEO;
    }
    else {
        videoUrl = Properties.MINE_WORK_VIDEO;
    }
}

}
```

**Base Fragment**

```
public abstract class BaseYoutubeFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
protected View fragmentView = null;
protected YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    assignViews();
    prepareViews();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fragmentView = inflater.inflate(getFragmentContentView(), container, false);


    youTubePlayerView = fragmentView.findViewById(getYoutubePlayerView());
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(com.can_apps.eva_ngo.properties.Properties.API_KEY, this);


    return fragmentView;
}


///////////////////  ABSTRACT METHODS  ////////////////////
protected abstract int getFragmentContentView();        //Get Layout R.layout.name_file

protected abstract int getYoutubePlayerView();  //Get Container for YOutube Video

protected abstract void assignViews();          //Used for findById the params

protected abstract void prepareViews();         //Used for start the values of params

///////////////////  SHOW MESSAGES  ////////////////////
public void showErrorToast(Context context, final int message) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, getString(message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    View view = toast.getView();
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background_red_transparent);
    toast.show();
}

///////////////////  SNACK BAR  ////////////////////
public void showSnackBar(final int text) {
    Snackbar.make(Objects.requireNonNull(getView()), getString(text), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void showSnackBar(final int mainTextStringId, final int actionStringId, View.OnClickListener listener) {
    Snackbar.make(Objects.requireNonNull(getView()),
            getString(mainTextStringId),
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(getString(actionStringId), listener).show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the logcat it looks like your `YouTubePlayerView` is null when you are calling one of its methods.

The YouTube Player API is quite buggy and difficult to use correctly. To solve this problems (and others) I have built an alternative player [Android-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player), it's open source and you can do whatever you want with it.

In your case, you won't have to meddle with Fragments and transactions, since my `YouTubePlayerView` is just a regular view and requires no special Fragments or Activities. You can drop it wherever you want.

Hope it could be useful to you as well!